# Cannot create a WPA3 hotspot

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, kde

```
OS: Ubuntu 20.04
Desktop: KDE
```

Whenever I try to initialize a hotspot with WPA3 security, I see the following error messages:

```
wpa_supplicant[1281]: Using interface wlp2s0 with hwaddr 7c:76:35:fa:61:35 and ssid "xxxxx"
wpa_supplicant[1281]: Could not generate WPA IE.
wpa_supplicant[1281]: WPA initialization failed.
wpa_supplicant[1281]: Interface initialization failed
wpa_supplicant[1281]: wlp2s0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->DISABLED
wpa_supplicant[1281]: wlp2s0: AP-DISABLED
wpa_supplicant[1281]: wlp2s0: Unable to setup interface.
wpa_supplicant[1281]: Failed to initialize AP interface
wpa_supplicant[1281]: wlp2s0: interface state DISABLED->DISABLED
wpa_supplicant[1281]: wlp2s0: AP-DISABLED
wpa_supplicant[1281]: hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlp2s0 wasn't started
```

WPA/WPA2 (TKIP) and unsecured interfaces work without any issue.

Comment: Why exactly do you want WPA3? Any practical reasons or just because?

Comment: Well, the way I understand it WPA/WPA2 uses TKIP and WPA2/WPA3 uses AES which is considered more secure.

Comment: Yes, but you can use WPA2 with AES. Does that setup work for you?

Comment: I don't see this option in the KDE Network Manager. My phone is complaining that TKIP is being used.